# IndexedDB work in Android native app

Tags: java, android, indexeddb

We've got application to view some specific materials. Among material types there is `HTML5` presentation that is shown in `WebView` widget inside app. And now we need to get detailed information about this view (for example slide show duration, list element pick where it is available, etc).

**It is what customer wants - we can't change it.**

We decided to use `IndexedDB` inside `HTML5` to store information locally. Now storing works (as I know `:)` ). Next problem is to get this information by app and it is not solved yet. Unfortunately google didn't help me.

How to get information from `IndexedDB` file if I know its path? Or do you know another way to transfer data from html to native app?

P.S. Writing custom browser could not be solution.

**Update**

Found solution to load file from JS. In chrome browser it automatically saves in downloads. In android app I'm setting to `WebView` object `DownloadListener` to listen file save event.

Catching save file works perfect. But the url path is looks like `blob:file/...` and I can't get info from it. Tried using `ContentResolver`, create `File` object, replace `blob:` string with nothing, start `ACTION_VIEW` intent - nothing helped.

**Update**

Tried to use `DownloadManager` and `DownloadManager.Request` - it throws following exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can only download HTTP/HTTPS URIs: file:///fa4857ad-0e86-454a-a341-123729e9ece0
```

Same with `blob:file` uri.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We decided to use `ServerSocket` for localhost as web server on device. And then `Html` sends to it http responce. May be using java script binding as wrote @Michael2 whould be better, but our solution was realized before his post. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Is it a requirement to use IndexedDB for communication?

If not, you could add a javascript interface. Simply pass on the data as JSON string and then decode it on the java side.

https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript

Mind security (don't allow the user to browse to different pages, sanitize incoming data, ...) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the problem by hack by calling the JavaScript function from Java and returning the required attributes in specific pattern. To implement this

1. Create the javascript function which will return the attributes in
   specific pattern.
2. Create the WebChromClient and override onJsAlert() method. message
   parameter of onJsAlert has the returned string of message. Parse the
   message string to get the required attributes.
3. Call the JavaScript function from Java code to get the value.

   ```
   final class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
       @Override
       public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {
           result.confirm();
           // Parse the message to get the required attributes
           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           return true;
      }
   }
   ```

To call the JavaScript function to get the data use the below code. Here testFunction() is the fucntion which will return the data in string format.

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:alert(testFunction())");
```

Create the instance of WebChromeClient and set in webview and also don't forget to enable the JavaScript.

```
WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.web_view);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());
```